# Microsoft Cognitive Bing Search API (v5) returning incorrect results

Tags: r, rvest, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services, httr

I would like to take a beer and search on Bing to return a result from http://ratebeer.com. The results I've gotten are mostly good but some results are (what I think) wrong.

One of the beers I've encountered problems with is named "Kolk Maak Amber Ale".

Using R and the httr package, my code is:

```
url <- https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=Kolk+Maak+Amber+Ale+site:http://ratebeer.com/beer&mkt=en-us
res <- GET(url,
          add_headers("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"=APIkey))
```

where "APIkey" is my personal key from Microsoft-Cognitive-Services.
The results are:

```
> content(res)
$`_type`
[1] "SearchResponse"

$webPages
$webPages$webSearchUrl
[1] "https://www.bing.com/cr?IG=8E30DC638C5B48E592061644988A6924&CID=08A1C0B86E4C6A7527FCCADF6FAB6BD5&rd=1&h=28PvtjGreQkOBLSaPy_GCtmkd-G642-BVoJp814ve_8&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fsearch%3fq%3dKolk%2bMaak%2bAmber%2bAle%2bsite%253ahttp%253a%252f%252fratebeer.com%252fbeer&p=DevEx,5148.1"

$webPages$totalEstimatedMatches
[1] 3

$webPages$value
$webPages$value[[1]]
$webPages$value[[1]]$id
[1] "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v5/#WebPages.0"

$webPages$value[[1]]$name
[1] "North River Grisette du Noorden - ratebeer.com"

$webPages$value[[1]]$url
[1] "https://www.bing.com/cr?IG=8E30DC638C5B48E592061644988A6924&CID=08A1C0B86E4C6A7527FCCADF6FAB6BD5&rd=1&h=71h-PtMgTQkVXsH3vxpLLwGtkRp4nyYvBbVMTwc47XM&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.ratebeer.com%2fbeer%2fnorth-river-grisette-du-noorden%2f492033%2f&p=DevEx,5056.1"

$webPages$value[[1]]$displayUrl
[1] "https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/north-river-grisette-du-noorden/492033"

$webPages$value[[1]]$snippet
[1] "North River Grisette du Noorden a Traditional Ale beer by North ... Pours a hazed amber with a medium ... Jopen Stripbier 2016: Tania (Hanco Kolk) 82 Jopen Koyt 94"

$webPages$value[[1]]$dateLastCrawled
[1] "2017-04-13T12:56:00"


$webPages$value[[2]]
$webPages$value[[2]]$id
[1] "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v5/#WebPages.1"

$webPages$value[[2]]$name
[1] "Frankenheim Alt - ratebeer.com"

$webPages$value[[2]]$url
[1] "https://www.bing.com/cr?IG=8E30DC638C5B48E592061644988A6924&CID=08A1C0B86E4C6A7527FCCADF6FAB6BD5&rd=1&h=-1irhi3khCoAu383TebZwPJdZMjMAL9L5KH6Nfs668U&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.ratebeer.com%2fbeer%2ffrankenheim-alt%2f11335%2f&p=DevEx,5068.1"

$webPages$value[[2]]$displayUrl
[1] "https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/frankenheim-alt/11335"

$webPages$value[[2]]$snippet
[1] "... donkere mouten, aangebrande caramel, metalig bitter, aards, noten, nee hier maak je ... Bottle 3 cl. Pours a hazy amber with a ... Element Interval Ale ..."

$webPages$value[[2]]$dateLastCrawled
[1] "2017-04-11T15:13:00"


$webPages$value[[3]]
$webPages$value[[3]]$id
[1] "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v5/#WebPages.2"

$webPages$value[[3]]$name
[1] "Cervoise Lancelot - ratebeer.com"

$webPages$value[[3]]$url
[1] "https://www.bing.com/cr?IG=8E30DC638C5B48E592061644988A6924&CID=08A1C0B86E4C6A7527FCCADF6FAB6BD5&rd=1&h=Fsu_98e2uQEcyl7FovpvzwTjtwLnOJvGezmVQvKAbPY&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.ratebeer.com%2fbeer%2fcervoise-lancelot%2f9828%2f&p=DevEx,5080.1"

$webPages$value[[3]]$displayUrl
[1] "https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/cervoise-lancelot/9828"

$webPages$value[[3]]$snippet
[1] "Cervoise Lancelot a Traditional Ale beer by Lancelot, ... Slightly hazy amber with quick diminishing head. Sweet malts, ... (Hanco Kolk) 82"

$webPages$value[[3]]$dateLastCrawled
[1] "2017-04-13T18:28:00"




$rankingResponse
$rankingResponse$mainline
$rankingResponse$mainline$items
$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[1]]
$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[1]]$answerType
[1] "WebPages"

$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[1]]$resultIndex
[1] 0

$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[1]]$value
$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[1]]$value$id
[1] "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v5/#WebPages.0"



$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[2]]
$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[2]]$answerType
[1] "WebPages"

$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[2]]$resultIndex
[1] 1

$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[2]]$value
$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[2]]$value$id
[1] "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v5/#WebPages.1"



$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[3]]
$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[3]]$answerType
[1] "WebPages"

$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[3]]$resultIndex
[1] 2

$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[3]]$value
$rankingResponse$mainline$items[[3]]$value$id
[1] "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v5/#WebPages.2"
```

As you can see here, none of the three beers listed show the correct beer which is searched for (Kolk Maak Amber Ale). However, if I follow the search response link from

```
content(res)$webPages$webSearchUrl
[1] "https://www.bing.com/cr?IG=8E30DC638C5B48E592061644988A6924&CID=08A1C0B86E4C6A7527FCCADF6FAB6BD5&rd=1&h=28PvtjGreQkOBLSaPy_GCtmkd-G642-BVoJp814ve_8&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fsearch%3fq%3dKolk%2bMaak%2bAmber%2bAle%2bsite%253ahttp%253a%252f%252fratebeer.com%252fbeer&p=DevEx,5148.1"
```

using a browser(Chrome/Firefox/IE) I get the correct beer as a first result.

Why is this happening? Why do all search values return the wrong url, but using a physical browser for it returns the right url? Other beers that I have tested this on return the right url.

Comment: When I follow your last URL with my web browser, there is only one result - "Jopen Librije’s Bier". Definitely not "Kolk Maak Amber Ale". If I search for "Kolk Maak Amber Ale" directly on ratebeer.com, I got no results. So, I think that this is happening because you are searching for something that is not in their database.

Comment: The beer is found on ratebeer.com. Actually, using [Bing search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Kolk+Maak+Amber+Ale+site%3Aratebeer.com&qs=n&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=kolk+maak+amber+ale&sc=0-19&sk=&cvid=E1B7C2F64C194BE4BEC8ED1FF849CE7D) works completely fine:

Answer (score 0):

This is very interesting.  If you type this into the search box, with pluses, you get the right results from Bing.  Without them, you don't get the right page:

Kolk+Maak+Amber+Ale+site:ratebeer.com

Also, this version provides the right result:
site:ratebeer.com Kolk Maak ale amber

But this version doesn't work:
site:ratebeer.com Kolk Maak amber ale